# Error on deserialization of Array Collection in Flex: RangeError: Error #2006

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, serialization, blazeds, amf

I am getting this error during serialization:

> RangeError: Error #2006: The supplied
>   index is out of bounds.
>   The error occurs in AbstractMessage.as when it attempts to read input of timestamp.

After that my fault handler gets this error:

> faultCode:Server.Acknowledge.Failed
>   faultString:'Didn't receive an
>   acknowledge message' faultDetail:'Was
>   expecting
>   mx.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessage,
>   but received null'

It appears to be happening as a result of an **ArrayCollection** coming back from the server.

Is it necessary to create custom classes to handle serialization of ArrayCollections with custom objects as shown [here](http://iamjosh.wordpress.com/2007/12/12/serialization-of-custom-collections-for-flex-data-services/)?

I've also followed the serialization recommendations [here](http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2008/03/25/flex-air-serialization-lessons-learned/) with no luck.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was correcting a mistake in writeExternal on the Java side. I was being very careful about the order of serialization but was writing an int as an object using writeObject.  This will cause errors in completely unrelated code on the client side after it tries to readInt.

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this error myself, and it turns out it is caused by the Flash Builder Network monitor being enabled!! FB 4.0.1 this is.

I was going nuts for not finding the reason, so sharing it here for your peace of mind.